# Not comparing equal `a==aa` although when printed the output is equal

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using python 2.7. I am trying to match two values

I am having the code something like following

```
a=field [0] ["inv"] ##This is json calling
aa=purchase [11] [0]   
print type(a)
print a
print type(aa)
print aa
if aa==a:
   print "same"
else:
   print "Not same"
```

when I execute the code I am getting following output

```
<type 'str'>
28
<type 'str'>
28
Not same
```

Why I am getting this output.I am having matching values. But why  I am getting the output as `not same`.

What is the issue behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well .. there are [characters that do not show up when printed (whitespace)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.whitespace) and after your last "normal" character: `' '`, `'\r'` `'\t'` `'\n'` and others.

Check

```
if len(aa) != len(a):
    print "Invisible characters - length different" 
    print "'{}' vs '{}'".format(aa,a)
```

Using [`rstrip()` (doku-link)](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#string.rstrip) to remove unwanted whitespace

```
if aa.rstrip()==a.rstrip():   # avoid "a" vs "a    " comparing to not equal
    print "same"
else:
    print "Not same"
```

helps.

Following this also helps: [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

**Demo**:

```
a  = "ff   "  # 'invisible' difference
aa = "ff"
print type(a)
print a
print type(aa)
print aa

if len(aa) != len(a):
    print "Invisible characters - length different" 
    print "'{}' vs '{}'".format(aa,a)

if aa.rstrip()==a.rstrip():
   print "same"
else:
   print "Not same"
```

Output:

```
<type 'str'>
ff   
<type 'str'>
ff
Invisible characters - length different
'ff' vs 'ff   ' 
same
```

Comment: For some cases the flow goes to both if and else part and give both the output.How can I correct that?

Comment: @Dines check your code line for line - it does NOT do the `if` and `else` of the same statement. You either have some indentation error or some stray `print` that outputs the same as in one of your conditional branches.